# How to out put a message each time a Tab is selected?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

I have an android program with 3 tabs. When I click on the “Map Tab” I want it to display “Map is Selected” message as shown in the picture bellow. But if I click on “Name” tab and then come back to the “Map Tab” the second time, the “Map is Selected Again” message wouldn’t show up in the screen. How can I make the “Map” tab display “Map is Selected Again” message each time I choose that tab? Can you edit the following code and show with an example about how to use OnTabChangeListener?

```
public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main4);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Map is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
}

public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Map Selected Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
} }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your Activity that extends TabActivity you could implement tab listener on change action like:

```
    public class SomeClass extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener{
    ...
    ...
    //and then override onTabChanged action like:

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabName) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
               "Map is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
             ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement OnTabChangeListener for event handling for the tabs.

Comment: **Please stop indenting your paragraphs**. Learn to use the editor correctly, and stop relying on other people making your posts readable.

Comment: Sorry ,I am new in stackoverflow. next time there is no chance to mistake.

Comment: @android_dev it wasn't your fault. I re edited my original question. So, probably the other guy thought you are just repeating the same thing I said about using `OnTabChangeListener`. If you can, can you please read my updated original question and give me an example of how to use `OnTabChangeListener`. Thanks a lot.